# onclick is not working inside map function

Tags: reactjs, atlaskit

I am trying to call onClick function on DropdownItem, it's working outside of map function but inside map function it's not working without any errors .

How to implement that?

ReactJs and Atlaskit packages I have used.

```
<Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
                                   <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown</DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem disabled>Action</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem divider />
      <DropdownItem> <div onClick={() => console.log('This will fire!')}>
                                            Another Action
                                          </div></DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After doing [more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: You can use onChange on dropdown. or you can create nested Dropdown id you want to use onclick.